# Localization App crashes on Android 4.0

Tags: android, localization

I have developed an app on Android target version 2.2.

I implemented localization in it for three languages and it works fine on `ldpi`, `mdpi` & `hdpi` devices of version 2.2 to 2.3.x, but it crashes on Android 4.x devices.

for Dutch I have used below folders and similarly for other languages:

> drawable-de-rDE
>
> drawable-de-rDE-hdpi
>
> drawable-de-rDE-mdpi
>
> drawable-de-rDE-xhdpi

**Error:**

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02002a a=-1 r=0x7f02002a}
```

**Note :**
When i have put images in `drawable-xhdpi` it works fine.

Can someone please guide me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you provide [default resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#defaults-r-important), or in other words: is any of the three languages the default? Also, on a side note: Dutch = nl, German = de.

Comment: Wether i have to considers one language defualt..? 
I have considered dirctly de, it & fr folders.
Should i place images from de folder in android defulat drwable folder?

Comment: Have you read the link I pointed out? It explains *"Why Default Resources Are Important"* and quite likely the origin of your error. You may first want to try without the region specifier, but ultimately you shoud add default resources anyhow. It appears your ICS device does not resolve to the resource paths you currently have, of which the localization appears the most straightforward culprit.

Comment: ok MH it worked for me,but now problem is my defualt language is DE but suppose i change my device language to IT, then it should show IT splashscreen but it shows DE splashscreen and then loads IT contents.
Since we have put DE images in android defualt folder.

Comment: One more thing MH,it only changes Values folder,whereas images are same as DE folder.It dont take images from IT or Fr folder.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but the reason it's not grabbing images from the it/fr resource folders is because your ICS device does not seem to resolve those correctly. I mean, that's the whole reason you even started this question, right? You need to figure out why that is the case - default resources, although highly recommened, will not magically make it work for all languages. Start by making the resource folders less strict and see if that makes any difference. E.g. my best guess is that the ICS device may not be set to 'de/it/fr' language, and/or 'rDE/rIT/rFR' region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lot of search i finally got solution for my question.

I Created a **res/drawable-de/** folder that includes an icon that the application will use whenever the language is set to **German but the location is not Germany**.

Difference in creating  drawable-de & drawable-de-rDE is ass follows:

```
     drawable-de - Defualt German language folder

     drawable-de-rDE - German Language images folder with **rDE** specifying region. 

     rCH - German language in China
     drawable-fr-rCA - French language in Canada.
```

This is how it solved my problem.

Thank you all for helping me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed layout qualifiers and values qualifiers.

Languages files should be in values/strings.xml for the default language, values-de/strings.xml for German, and so on...

Comment: These all things are correct since my app run well on android 2.x devices and crashes only on Android 4.x devices.